# compareAndSet memory effects when expected==update

Tags: java, concurrency, compare-and-swap

Java exposes the CAS operation through its atomic classes, e.g.

`AtomicInteger.compareAndSet(expected,update)`

When `expected == update`, are these calls a no-op or do they still have the memory consistency effects of a volatile read+write (as is the case when `expected != update`)?

Comment: FYI: I have deleted my answer.  I misread the code am no longer sure that the `compareAndSet(...)` actually makes a `volatile` read of the underlying field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went through the native code and there does not appear to be any difference in relation to the values being equal.  Specifically in this case since integer equivalence doesnt do so on the reference.

It will run through the same logic with same memory consistencies in the event `expected != update`

One note is that there will always be at least a volatile load on the field's location, so you at the very least will have a volatile read of the backing int field.

Comment: I can't quite parse the first paragraph John. Difference to what?  Can you rephrase or am I just slow today?  :-)

Comment: @Gray Sorry! It does read a little confusing.  There is no difference in the operations if expected and updated are equal.  Meaning it will execute the same compare and swap function on the int values which are pointing to different locations in memory.  At the end it will still do a swap of the values which will carry the same memory consistency if they werent equal.

Comment: Can you edit your post @John to make it more clear for posterity?  I still don't quite understand "Specifically in this case since integer equivalence doesnt do so on the reference".

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is no check for `expected == update` and no change in behaviour. To do so could add cycles if the hardware didn't do it already, which I suspect it doesn't.

I wouldn't write code which depends on side effects of calling CAS in any case.

You could add the check yourself if you think it is likely of course.